# Observer for Magent product after save

Tags: magento

I am trying to add Observer to the Product status update event on backend. But it does not triggering the event.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>      
<config>     
    <modules>      
        <Mage4u_Customredirect>     
            <version>0.1.0</version>      
        </Mage4u_Customredirect>      
    </modules>     
    <global>        
        <events>     
            <catalog_product_status_update>      
                <observers>     
                    <Mage4u_Customredirect_Catalog_product>     
                        <type>singleton</type>  
                    <class>mage4u_customredirect/observer</class>   <method>on_catalog_product_status_update</method>  </Mage4u_Customredirect_Catalog_product>              

                </observers>  
            </catalog_product_status_update> 
        </events>  
    </global>    
</config>
```

And the observer function is to receive the status of the product that was updated and based on that i need to update it in another server.

```
<?php


class Mage4u_Customredirect_Model_Observer
{


    public function on_catalog_product_status_update(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {  
        Mage::log("test " ,null,"test");

        var_dump($observer);die();  

        }


}


?>
```

But it  does not triggering this event. Please can someone tel me why its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the same notation here for class name as you use in Mage::getModel() factory method, e.g.:  `<class>mage4u_customredirect/observer</class>`. Do not forget delete cache after this change to make it work.

Comment: Hi, yes i updated class name as you mentioned. But now it gaves file include error. ** ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Mage4u/Customredirect/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/server/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Mage4u/Customredirect/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/ser/app/code/local:/var/sef/app/code/community:/var/server/app/code/core:/var/server/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/ser/lib/Varien/Autoload.php**. Note its magento 1.9 Enterprise edition.

Comment: It fails to find file with model. Can you show here example, how do you create instance of some another model in your code. From first glance it looks like you have capital letter in the middle of some folder name, for example `Customredirect`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `CustomRedirect`.

Comment: Hi, Please see the question again. Updated exact code that i have with the observer and xml file.

Comment: Hmm, can you try somewhere in your module code create observer model instance via Mage::getModel('mage4u_customredirect/observer'). Also, I don't see models section in your config.xml file. Did you remove it when pasted code here or it is really absent? Without this section magento will not register your models in autoload.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your great help. I missed the models section, thats why it cant find the observer.